# Hot wire showing hot with no neutral or ground

Tags: wiring

I have had problems with power since maintenance guy changed the breaker I disconnected the neutral and ground in my main panel and disconnected the hot I am having trouble with

I still show the one hot to ground 122v and I show 110von the disconnected hot
How is this possible with themain ground and neutral gone and I disconneced all neutrals

Comment: Just a silly question but why are you simply disconnecting things without knowing what you're doing or why you are doing it?  Sounds like a recipe for disaster.

Comment: Do you really mean that you disconnected the main ground, main neutral, and one of the main hots in the main panel, or are we misunderstanding?

Comment: Also punctuation is _critical_ "...maintenance guy changed the breaker. I disconnected..." is different from "...maintenance guy changed the breaker I disconnected...". Did he change a breaker then you disconnected it, or did he change a breaker that you had disconnected.

Comment: _Where_ are you showing 120v hot-to-ground? In the panel? At a switch or outlet? If it's at a fixture, it's possible that there's a MWBC which is providing power and points out why there are special rules about how they _must_ be wired to be safe.

Answer (score 0):

When wires are in close contact the live ones induce voltages on the ones that are not powered. We call this a phantom voltage
The voltage is real but there is no potential or current.

There are volt meters that have low impedance and eliminate this phantom voltage, most pros don’t use low z meters because the low impedance makes for inaccurate readings and we usually want to see the real values our meters are showing because other issues can be hidden with low z meters.

To prove you don’t even need to have a complete circuit use your meter ac volts plug 1 probe into a receptacle on the hot (small slot) and hold the other probe and you will measure a few volts.

Comment: possible typo in first paragraph, last sentence